# Warning when adding multiple VirtualHosts on port 443 - "_default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence"

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and I have the following 4 VirtualHost entries in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

The 4 VirtualHost entries are for 2 separate sites, `test.example.com` and `test2.example.com`, one entry each for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/test
   ServerName test.example.com
   # Other settings goes here
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/test
   ServerName test.example.com
   # Other settings goes here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/test2
   ServerName test2.example.com
   # Other settings goes here
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/test2
   ServerName test2.example.com
   # Other settings goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

**My problem**
When I save and restart apache, I get this warning:-

```
* Restarting web server apache2
[Sun Feb 17 18:30:09 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
 ... waiting [Sun Feb 17 18:30:10 2013] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
```

And I get the contents of `/var/www/test` when I open both `test.example.com` and `test2.example.com`

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Is `NameVirtualHost *:443` in your configuration?

Comment: @faker, not it was not. I added it and the problem was solved :) Thanks. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it. Also can you tell me why adding it was necessary, since I hadnt added NameVirtualHost *:80 for HTTP and still both the VirtualHosts on port 80 woked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add `NameVirtualHost *:443` for it to work.
`NameVirtualHost *:80` must also be in your configuration, it is probably set by default, but I don't use Ubuntu so I'm not sure in which file.

Also a word of advice:
Running multiple HTTPS sites on a single IP might have it's drawbacks, specifically older clients (IE8/Windows XP) will not support SNI.
It may make perfect sense in your situation (only for testing, *.example.com wildcard certificate is being used, etc.) but you should be aware of this.

Comment: I was struggling with this today, everything worked instantly after adding the line. Thank you.

Comment: On my Ubuntu server I had to add this to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. In there, `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` already had a `Listen 443` and I added `NameVirtualHost *:443` there. It also refers to some other file in the comments, but that didn't exist on my server. Run an `apachectl -t` to check if your configuration is correct.